# Checkbox in ListView non-selectable with event handler

Tags: android

Pretty simple, but its driving me crazy. In the getView method of my custom list adapter I have this code:

```
chkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.camAlertChk);


    chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn, boolean isChecked) 
        {
            camera.alertsEnabled = isChecked;
            AlertOrchestrator.getInstance().setAlertsEnabled(camera);
        }
    });
```

With this code my checkbox is non selectable.  In fact my Activity has two listviews in it and this code makes all listviews (and the checkbox in the top listview) unselectable.

However, if I take out my two lines of code in onCheckedChanged, lists and the checkbox become selectable again.  The onCheckedChanged event is called just fine.  It just don't like any code it in.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You say that these checkboxes are a part of ListView items.  Is the ListView consuming the touch event?

Comment: the listview is not consuming the touch event.  When I take out my two lines of code, the onCheckedChanged is called, and my onListItemClick is also called. Put those two lines of code back and nothing is called

Comment: So this is the problem line:  AlertOrchestrator.getInstance().setAlertsEnabled(camera);
It is a singleton.  Why would this not work?

Comment: Ok this was the problem: In get view I had this:
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cameraalertrow,null);

I forgot to check and make sure they weren't null.